# app view cache is not working

Tags: express

I'm fairly new to Express and am having an issue.  I have node_env set to production and app.get('view cache') is returning true.  However, it doesn't appear to be caching my jade baseed views.  I can see get with a 304, but my view render is still being called every time.

Am I misunderstanding what this setting is for?

Edit:  I guess this setting is really just to make views templates perform better in production.  Am I to assume then the express does not support caching of dynamically generated view content?

I noticed adding res.header('Cache-Control', 'max-age=60, must-revalidate');

Is there a cleaner way to do this?  thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the 'view cache' setting is true, it caches the compiled javascript of the jade templates.

It doesn't however, cache the jade into a fully static document.

If you wished to do this, you could render the jade once in your app and store the result as a file or in memory. Then you just serve this rendered jade to your client.